# python, Edge, open split screen and open pdf on right

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, browser, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

How I can open split screen with Edge browser with python in auto mode?

I try to google/chatgpt this question, but no big success.
seems this feature new may be januar 2024

can this be done with other browsers?

or only way is image recognition?

UPD: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver/issues/137

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the functionality that can open split screen in Edge WebDriver. It doesn't have keyboard shortcut either, so I think we can't use split screen in auto mode for now.

I suggest that you can submit new feature request in [Edge WebDriver](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver/issues) repo. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: microsoft have demonstration for split screen, but how they control it is riddle
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/features/split-screen?form=MA13FJ

Comment: Yes, it only shows how to use split screen, no deeper instruction for it.